# Windows 8 store apps and ko comment binding

Tags: knockout.js, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am using the knockout [comment binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) (called: containerless control flow syntax). However it works fine in a browser but not in a windows 8 store app. Does Visual Studio stripe out all comments? Is there any way to use the comment binding?

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: journal">
   <!-- ko if: typeof $data!=='string' -->
     <li data-bind="text:Name"></li>
   <!-- /ko -->
   <!-- ko if: typeof $data==='string' && $data!='' -->
     <li data-bind="text:$data"></li>
   <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

The error is: `Name is undefined`.

If I make the following, name is defined:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: journal">
     <li data-bind="text:Name"></li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to use the containerless control flow syntax in windows 8 store apps?

---

**Solution**

I found a solution with this [great tutorial](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html).

I was loading the data with jQuery before I bind it with ko. While this loading, windows seem to remove unsafe code. With the following function I was able to append the "unsafe" code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "msappx://journal.html",
    success: function (data) {

  if (typeof winjs !== undefined) {
    MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function () {
      $(jqAppendTo).append(data);
    });
  }
  else {
    $(jqAppendTo).append(data);
  }

    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure about windows 8 store apps, but with an aspx page, ko containerless binding works

Answer (score 0):

You could use a computed observable to simplify your knockout template...

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: fitered_journal">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Paired with...

```
$ ->

    viewmodel = ->
        self = this

        self.journal = ko.observableArray([
            '',
            'Some string data',
            {Name: 'other string data'}
        ])

        self.fitered_journal = ko.computed(->
            items = []
            for item in self.journal()
                if typeof item isnt 'string'
                    items.push(item.Name)
                else if typeof item is 'string' and item isnt ''
                    items.push(item)
            return items
        )

    ko.applyBindings(viewmodel)
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2sfR/)

Comment: thx for your help. Anyway the example above is simplified. Normaly the !string binding is much more complexer. But I found my error.